# How to use tabulator.info callbacks when table was already initialized?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

tabulator comes with quite a lot of callbacks: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/callbacks

The problem that I have is that I have an already initialized tabulator and I don't know how to add a custom callback to that table. In my case this is a download callback (http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/callbacks#download), but it could be any other callback as well.

Is there a way to listen for this callbacks somewhat like this:

```js
$(document).on('cellClick', myTabulator, function(e, cell) {
  console.log('clicked cell:', cell);
});
```

Thanks for your help!

PS: This is my example setup:

```js
var tab = new Tabulator({ ... no control over this part ... });

// --- other file ---
// now I want to listen for several events here
// finding the table is quite hidden in the docs:
// http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/options#find-table
var myTab = Tabulator.prototype.findTable("#example-table")[0];

// does something like this exist?
// or is it somehow possible?
myTab.on('cellClick', function() { ... });
```

Comment: So does the initialized table already have a download option?
It would seem to me somewhat unstable to create a callback that may override one in the table code you have no control over or be overridden by same. I would think grabbing the element and creating you own .on() would be safer.

Comment: thx @AdrianKlaver what do you mean by "grabbing the element and creating you own .on() would be safer." Could you provide an example? Maybe I'm missing something fundamental :)

Comment: A quick and dirty example:
https://jsfiddle.net/aklaver/e1vujg74/57/

Comment: Thx @AdrianKlaver that seems to work for clicks (native js event), but how would I interact with the table using tabulator events like rowSelected?
Imagine I have a table that is already set up. Now I want to register "plugins" on that table, eg one that shows the number of selected rows and one that logs all selected rows to the console. How would I do that if all I have is an initialized table?
The problem is (as far as I understand) that I would need to reinit the table with the according callback. But I need 2 actions, not only one, so I'd need to wrap them in a function() { one + two }

Comment: ...But I can't do that, because I want to keep plugins organized in separate files. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: So where is the code for the table coming from? Do you have any control over it?

Comment: thx again @AdrianKlaver; I'm developing a module (php backend) that uses tabulator for data display. I want to develop plugins (like button xls export, csv export, ajax reload, etc); those plugins are defined in the backend and come with their own JS files. And I want (need) to modify the table there and NOT in the initial config (because that would get a total mess). Different plugins may need to do actions based on events (like row select), so I can't simply add a callback on init of the table...

Comment: Isn't that just replicating what Tabulator already does. Wouldn't it be easier just to extend the existing modules:http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/modules

Comment: Hey @AdrianKlaver, thx, seems that finally you got me on track :) Looks like this is the way to go! Thank you for your help :))

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a way to directly change the callbacks once the table has been initialized, but you could use a bit of trickery to solve the issue by storing your callbacks in an external object that you then reference.

We start by defining out callbacks object:

```js
var callbacks = {
    cellClick:function(e, cell){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Then we create out Tabulator as normal, but when we define the ***cellClick*** callback we will use an anonymous function that then references our callback object:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    cellClick:function(e, cell){
        //e - the click event object
        //cell - cell component

        callbacks.cellClick(e, cell);
    },
});
```

By doing it this way it means that if we want to change our callback later, we simply replace it in the callback object:

```js
callbacks.cellClick = function(e, cell){
    //do something else
}
```

That way we don't need to rebuild the table, the reference changes and that is all

Comment: Thx oli, but that would still mean that I need to define callbacks at table initialisation. Wouldn't it be possible that the callbacks fire an individual event on the table dom element or the like so that one can simply listen for that and do custom actions?

Comment: The approach outlined above does work for that, you only have to define the generic callbacks in the table, you can add the actual functionality in the callbacks object any time after that, using the method outlined. if you wrap the calls to the `callbacks` in an `if` statement to check they exist before calling then you don't even need to do that.

Comment: Tabulator specifically dosnt call any global events as the whole point is that it keeps its functionality isolated to the table so there is no risk it interferes with anything else. Click events will still propagate to the rest of the DOM but they will not have a cell component that allows access to manipulate the cell

Comment: You could just as easily trigger your own custom events from inside the Tabulator callbacks and then listen for them outside. You would still have to define them on the table, but then it would be your choice to listen for them later

Comment: Thx so far, oli. I need to do some more testing with my setup so that I can explain the problem better (or solve it, we'll see) :)